# Mid function in my code returns an error, can you help me?

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting an error `BC30451:Object Mid is not declared.` when trying to use **Mid** function in my code, to assign a certain part of a main string, to a String variable.

My code looks like this:

```
Dim Main As String
Dim Prim4 As String
Dim Scnd3 As String

  Main = "Variable from plc here"
  Main = Main.Trim()

  Prim4 = Mid(Main, 1, 4)
  Scnd3 = Mid(Main, 6, 3)
```

I'm coding in Sysmac Studio Ver.1.30, which supports some VB and .NET Framework 3.5 functions including said **Mid** Function.

-Toni-

Comment: Try using the [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) function. E.g., `Prim4 = Main.Substring(0, 4)`.

Comment: I can get it working with substring, but it returns error about string length, "startindex cannot be larger than length of a string " in the HMI view, but I think this is because I'm calling this sub constantly. Thanks for a quick answer.

Comment: @Toni What do you want to happen if the string is too short? E.g. you ask it for the 6th character of a string which is 2 characters long?

Comment: @Toni I'm not familiar with Sysmac Studio, but does putting `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings` at the beginning of the file let it resolve it?

Comment: Note that if you switch to `Substring`, that's 0-indexed while as I recall `Mid` is 1-indexed.

Comment: @Toni As Craig said, the `startIndex` parameter of `Substring` is zero-based. Also, `Substring` will throw an exception if you try to exceed the string length. If you want something that works exactly like the legacy `Mid` function, [you can write one yourself](https://pastebin.com/X3T2G6Ly).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, that solves it, though I moved the work that this code would have handled to a PLC, and I'm getting results what I need. Sorry for not updating earlier, thanks everyone for help. But for the future, sysmac needs the MID function to be defined/found with Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings . Substring returned some problems, when I tried to run it.